# selector css3 :checked not working in IE8 (using ie7.js)

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, checked

I have radio buttons like this:

```
<input class="check" type="radio" id="radio1" name="group"/>
<label for="radio1">vrai</label>
<input class="check" type="radio" id="radio2" name="group"/>
<label for="radio2">faux</label>
<input class="check" type="radio" id="radio3" name="group"/>
<label for="radio3">75</label>
<input class="check" type="radio" id="radio4" name="group"/>
<label for="radio4">18</label>
```

I had the selected class when that are `:checked`, but strangely even using ie7.js it does not work in ie8.

Here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:checked').addClass("selected");
    $('input').click(function () {
        $('input:not(:checked)').removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

Comment: you should try using onchange event instead

Comment: Where should i use onchange ?

Comment: With `ie7.js` the `:checked` selector should work fine in IE7/8, [there's even a test case for it](http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/checked.html) resembling exactly what you're doing.

Comment: instead of click, use change and see if that makes any difference. I know that using click for checkbox can cause issue in older IE, not sure for radios so try it

Comment: If you're just using jQuery's `:checked`, you shouldn't need ie7.js; jQuery should be working out the selector. In fact, jQuery won't even use ie7.js even if you are including it in your site; ie7.js will only come into play in this context if you're using the selector directly in your CSS code.

Comment: I used $("input[name=group]:checked"), and works, without ie7.js

Comment: What version of jQuery? 2.x eliminated support for old IE versions...

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it has to do but I would rewrite the following and see if it changes something:

```
$('input').not('input:checked').removeClass("selected");
$(this).addClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `change()` instead of `click()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:checked').addClass("selected");
    $('input').change(function () {       // <--- HERE
        $('input:not(:checked)').removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

Comment: Does not work because IE8 does not recognize pseudo selectors

Comment: With change still not working in IE8. And i know about the pseudo selectors thats why i use IE7.js (google service)

Answer (score 0):

Hy,
 i have made pure javascript solution for you which works accross all browser. please have a look if it is useful for you

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
                function check(selected)
                {
                  var inputs= document.getElementsByTagName('input');
                  for(i=0 ; i < inputs.length; ++i)
                  {

                       inputs[i].className="";
                  }
                  selected.className="selected";
                }
        </script>

        <input class="check" type="radio" id="radio1" name="group" onclick="check(this);"/>
        <label for="radio1">vrai</label>
        <input class="check" type="radio" id="radio2" name="group" onclick="check(this);"/>
        <label for="radio2">faux</label>
        <input class="check" type="radio" id="radio3" name="group" onclick="check(this);"/>
        <label for="radio3">75</label>
        <input class="check" type="radio" id="radio4" name="group" onclick="check(this);"/>
        <label for="radio4">18</label>
```

Comment: Hi, thank for your solution but it still not working in IE8 =/ Dont know how i can fix it really.